# Which In Memory Databases Support PIVOT?

Tags: java, database

My production database is Oracle uses views that make use of the Oracle Pivot command http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Up until now I had been using h2 for my java testing, however, Pivot support is only on the roadmap http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html

Are there any in memory databases I can use in java that support Pivot?

Comment: Another good example why using a different DBMS for testing and  production is a bad idea

Comment: Thanks for your positive contribution to the question.